# How to determine MaxConnections for Socket.Listen()?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

The `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Listen()` function requires a `backlog` argument, which is the max number of connections that `Listen()` can queue up.

[From the MSDN documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket.listen)

> To determine the maximum number of connections you can specify,
>   retrieve the `MaxConnections` value.

[So I click on `MaxConnections` and the link takes me to the page for `SocketOptionName Enumeration`, which says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname)

> **MaxConnections:**      Not supported; will throw a SocketException if
>   used.

So the documentation for this `MaxConnections` enumeration says not to use it, but doesn't give an alternative. How do I determine the max connections, so that I have a value to pass into the `Socket.Listen()` function?

Answer (score 2):

Exception will be thrown when you will try to set socket **option** and use `MaxConnections` as an **option** name, e.g.

`listenSocket.SetSocketOption(..., SocketOptionName.MaxConnections, ...);`

In contrast, as a `backlog` argument it is meant to be used.